# Pod Dependency conflicting names

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoapods

I develop two frameworks (Framework A and Framework B) and deliver them via Cocoapods.Framework A has a dependency on Framework B . Below you can see the pod spec for a Framework A:

```
s.ios.dependency 'Framework B/Dynamic', "~> 1.0.0"
```

If I install both frameworks via `CocoaPods` and specify them both in the `Podifle` , I receive an error:

```
[!] The 'PodsTarget' target has frameworks with conflicting names: framework_b_name.xcframework.
```

I wonder, is there any .podspec argument or build settings for `Framework A` , which could help me to solve this issue. For example, cocoapods will not install additional `Framework A` in case, if both Framework A and B have been specified in the `Podfile` ? I want this issue to be solved on the dependency side and not on the side of the client (person, who installs the pod).

I have tried to use weak linking flag in the build settings as well, as removing `/Dynamic` from the .podspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is my solution for the current problem:

In Podfile I have my FrameworkB (without specific version it pulls the latest major, let's say `2.0.0`). In my Podspec I had version of a dependency set to `~> 1.0.0`], which will pull any version, that is `higher, than 1.0.0, but lower than 2.0.0`. Plus, I pulled `FrameworkB/Dynamic`, which led to creation of `Dynamic` folder, so after `pod install/update`, I had following project struct:

```
project
│   /..../    
│
└───Pods
│   │   FrameworkB.framework
│   │
│   └───Dynamic
│          FrameworkB.framework
```

Changing version in the .podspec file to `>=1.0.0` fixed the problem.